# Ignore a CombinePdf exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, exception, combine-pdf

I want to only skip the CombinePdf::ParsingError (Optional Content PDF files aren't supported and their pages cannot be safely extracted.) when i upload a pdf file inside my begin/rescue but it's not working, how can i do ?

```
begin
  FileManager::PdfValidation.new(uploaded_files)
rescue ParsingError => e
end
```

Comment: I don't know combine-pdf, but if what you write is true, it should be `rescue CombinePdf::ParsingError`. Or do I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
CombinePDF.load("your_file.pdf", unsafe: true, allow_optional_content: true)
```

Source: https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf/issues/28#issuecomment-1376413479

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the code of [combine_pdf](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf/blob/master/lib/combine_pdf/parser.rb#L536) you see that it *is* possible to parse files with optional content.

Also, the README states:

> Sometimes the CombinePDF will raise an exception even if the PDF could be parsed (i.e., when PDF optional content exists)... I find it better to err on the side of caution, although for optional content PDFs an exception is avoidable using CombinePDF.load(pdf_file, allow_optional_content: true).

You could try that.

Alternatively, depending on what your use case is, you can try [pdf-reader](https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader) (if you just wanna read something from the PDF) or [HexaPDF](https://hexapdf.gettalong.org) (which is a **fully-featured PDF library**; n.b. I'm the author of HexaPDF).